# Dynamic period subsetting via xts in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

Assume we have an xts object of OHLC returns series for SPX (`SPX`)

If I wanted to dynamically subset these returns so that we could, say, subset the period from `Business Day 9` of every month to `2 business days before the end of the month`, what would be the most efficient way to do this with xts?

I've tried playing around with nesting some combinations of `.index` / `xts` functions like

```
SPX[.indexmday(SPX)==1]
```

as well as some date functions out of `RQuantLib` and `lubridate` but with varying levels of success.

I'm sure there's a fairly convenient and efficient way of doing thisAny advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using negative values for `head` and `tail`:

```
SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo", auto.assign=FALSE)
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(SPX, 'months'), function(x) tail(head(x, -2), -9)))
```

It splits by "months", then applies a function to each month.  The function gets all but the first 9 days of all but the last 2 days in the `xts`.  Finally, `rbind` the results together into a single `xts` object.

**Edit:**

You can use `xts::first` and `xts::last` instead of `head` and `tail` so that it will work with frequencies other than daily.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(SPX, 'months'), function(x) {
  first(xts::last(x, "-2 days"), "-9 days")
}))
```

**Update to address comment:**

If you want to do other operations on the subsets, you need to check to make sure there's at least 1 row of data.  If, for a given month, there are no days in your xts object after the 9th and before the 2nd to last day, the anonymous function above will return `NULL`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(SPX, 'months'), function(x) {
  dat <- first(xts::last(x, "-2 days"), "-9 days")
  if (NROW(dat) > 0) OpCl(dat)
}))
```

Although, in this case, you can just call `OpCl()` on the results of my original answer to get the same result.

```
tmp <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(SPX, 'months'), function(x) {
  first(xts::last(x, "-2 days"), "-9 days")
}))
OpCl(tmp)
```

Comment: While we're at it, what do you think is the best method of deriving OpCl (or whatever standard periodicity) returns for each subperiod via your method? ie, instead of returning just the timeseries of prices for each subperiod, you finish with an object holding the OpCl returns?